# which is better way from performance point of view either use "Id" as selector or "Class" as selector in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-ui

HTML:

JQuery:
('.nameClass').click(myFunction);
or
('#txtName').click(myFunction);

In Jquery Which is best perform when we have 100's of control to apply this logic. And Why better perform ?

Answer (score 0):

Using id selector will be fast always as it returns single element but class selector will return one or more elements.

**NOTE** - You must ensure that id should be unique through out the DOM.

Comment: But in both cases it may iterate throw the DOM?

Comment: but search criteria is more restrictive using ID selector, hence once it finds element it will stop searching.

Comment: in case of id I need to write 100 selector  But if I use class then a single line code can be sufficient. So What if Class is used to improve maintainability of Jquery code.

Comment: Yes, for handling 100s of element, class is better choice instead of id. This will be easy for maintainability and extensibility.